# Avada portfolios

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to find a way to static the size of the portfolios as they become uneven due to multiple categories. I am using the Avada theme and if you go to the portfolios page (https://www.socalip.com/professionals/) you will see how some of the lower portfolios float lower than others.

Does anyone know of any CSS that might make those a static size? I'd like to keep them all uniform if possible. Apologies if i missed any important details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better to constrain the font size of the locations and designations, e.g: `.fusion-portfolio-content h4 a {
    font-size: 10px;
}` You see the thing is, those elements have their positions calculated on load and set with inline styles and update accordingly after the window resizes, they are also absolutely positioned and so are taken *out of the normal document flow* - so if you try to declare a `min-height` on the element, below the profile images, containing the text, they won't push down the elements below it.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within your question. A link to your web site does no one any good once you fix it or the link goes dead.

Comment: Ah ok, that gives me a better understanding of how those work. You were correct, setting the .fusion-portfolio-content h4 a { font-size: 10px; } (I made it slightly larger) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your position absolute is throwing everything out of wack. This will help you go around it

```
.fusion-portfolio-post.fusion-col-spacing {
     position: static !important;
}
```

I'm using both classes in the specificity in case the col-spacing class is also being used somewhere else, but to make it even better, add a hook class on your highest parent div that holds this component and add that to the specificity to make it even more specific and not mess up another component in your site.

For example

```
<div class="hook-class">
  <my shortcode for this component here/>
</div>

//CSS
.hook-class > .fusion-portfolio-post.fusion-col-spacing {
     position: static !important;
}
```

**EDIT (Aditional code you may need...Optional)**

The H4 tag will give you problems with longer names wrapping. I would ellipse those if I were you and keep font size for legibility purposes. But it's your choice nonetheless Notice Jeff in my screenshot

```
.fusion-portfolio-content h4 {
    width: 200px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Use specificity here as well.

Here is the test at different responsive breakpoints

> 1024px
>   [image]

991px
[image]

768px
[image]

<500px

[image]

Comment: Alright, but if you do that - you also throw the theme's responsive adjustments out of whack, since it will then negate any recalculations on positioning. You can get around this by fighting against the theme's styles and accounting for various viewport sizes with media queries - or even *just using flex* again (for everything) - but I wouldn't recommend it. It's just too much hassle. (Disclaimer: subjective opinion - not seeking debate)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I just tested it at different breakpoints (500px, 768px, 991px, and 1024 px) looks fine

Comment: Just gave it a quick test myself and I can confirm that - so colour me vaguely intrigued and mildly surprised. Although, for higher resolutions it seems to break the layout. Still should easy enough to fix.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yeah, considering he's altering code that is not his, this is probably the best he can do. Ideally, as you would agree, it is always better to write your own code. But I am familiar with Avada and I know how complex their framework is. #1 reason I don't use it. Too much bloat for something that can be done much easier with a blank boostrap template and build it from the ground up

Comment: Within reason - sometimes it may be better to work with the framework you have rather than against it. I see your point though. And yea, the bloat is real on Avada - whenever a suggestion is passed around to install with demo content I weep a little inside.

Comment: Designing is probably the most fun part of web design.  It's instant gratification. I usually use a simple bootstrap template and design as I please, build my own plugins, etc.